# How to check if a file with a .txt extension exists in a directory?

Tags: perl, file-exists

I want to know how to check if a directory has a file with `.txt` extension in it.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

Simply using glob :

```
if ( <*.txt> ) { ... }
```

Comment: ...or since people are so accustomed to seeing angle brackets used to read from files, `glob('*.txt')` does virtually the exact same thing while being less prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $dir = '.';  # current dir

opendir(DIRHANDLE, $dir) || die "Couldn't open directory $dir: $!\n";
my @txt = grep {  /\.txt$/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir DIRHANDLE;
closedir DIRHANDLE;

print ".txt files found" if (scalar(@txt));
```

As a bonus, all .txt files found are in array @txt.

Comment: No need for the `scalar`. `print ".txt files found" if @txt` is much nicer

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `*.txt` could actually be a directory. If it is files you are after, `grep` the `glob`:

```
if ( grep -f, glob '*.txt' ) { ... }
```